# Reputation league info not showing in the profile page of some users

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-leagues

I just noticed that some users do not have the "top X" blue box in their profile.

See for [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel):

> [image]

or [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard):

> [image]

While for [me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/209901/fedorqui?tab=profile) it works:

> [image]

Also for [Mad Scientist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151385/mad-scientist):

> [image]

I see this happening to some user profiles, but not others. It seems a bit random: I cannot find a pattern on when it is happening!

Comment: I see it for both these users now, but only after clicking onto the "Activity" tab of their profile; while for yourself & MadScientist it was there already. I assume it's a cache thing?

Comment: @TZHX yes! I see it also, but not for this user for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135565/journeyman-geek

Comment: again, once I clicked onto 'activity' tab it started appearing on the main tab -- I would _guess_ the information is only populated on that tab and then cached server-side.